# How to run HP UFT automation batch file in RDP machine without using ALM

Tags: testing, automation, hp-uft

In my project we are running the UFT scripts individually in RDP machine but that RDP wil get disconnect if screen is not active.
Could any one suggest me how to run all together scripts by using batch file in the remote machine without getting disconnected.also we are not using Hp ALm.
Thanks in advance!